# Failed to establish a new connection when creating a selenium bidi connection in a remote driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I try to create async bidi_connetction to use chrome devtools, it works locally but failed when I use remote driver that deployed in selenoid with the following error

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /json/version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x112ca03d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'
```

I have tried different parameters for capability. I also found somewhere that the `networkConnectionEnabled` parameter can be related to this, but it cannot be passed as a capability parameter. I am not sure on which side this problem is occurring. Is it a selenoid problem or a remote driver problem.